# How to pass python variable to a groovy script?

Tags: python, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a folder which contains a jenkins script(groovy script) and a python file, I need to pass a variable present in python file to groovy script. How to do this?

Comment: Pass it as an environment variable?

Comment: i guess groovy is calling python - then pass data through stdout. print something in python and capture stdout in groovy.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the variable to a file, then read the file in groovy script to get the variable.

```py
# Python script
with open('vars.txt') as fp:
  fp.write('key=val1')
```

```
# Jenkinsfile
stage() {
   steps {
      script {
         def vars = readProperties(file: 'vars.txt')
         echo vars['key']
      }
   }
}
```